# PostgreSQL Join with special condition

Tags: postgresql

Lets assume we have the following table1:

```
1 2 3
a x m
a y m
b z m
```

I want to do an inner join on the table

```
INNER JOIN tabel2 ON table1.2 = table2.2
```

Somehow like this, but additional a condition that the value of table1.1 not unique. Thus on table1.1 = b no inner join will occure in this example.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a an aggregate in a sub query is how I would do it

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1."2" = table2."2"
JOIN (
    SELECT "1" 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY "1"
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS sub_q
ON sub_q."1" = table1."1";
```

Another option might be a cte or temporary table to hold the rows you're joining on

```
WITH _cte AS 
(
SELECT "1"
FROM table1 
GROUP BY "1"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1."2" = table2."2"
JOIN _cte AS cte
ON cte."1" = table1."1";
```

temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tab
(
"1" varchar
);

INSERT INTO _tab
SELECT "1"
FROM table1 
GROUP BY "1"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1."2" = table2."2"
JOIN _tab AS tab
ON tab."1" = table1."1";
```

Comment: thx for ur reply, i had the same idea, but unfortunately the query select is huge with a lot of joins before. Thus the performace would be very bad...

Comment: Ok, I've edited with a couple more options which might be more performant